# add router and interface name matches from regex to dict with no duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, regex, juniper

I have a RegEx that extracts Juniper router and interface names from RANCID configs. I want to *properly* utilize a `dict`, `set` or `list` (doesn't honestly matter, I display a `dict` in my example) that will store the router names from my example text (the `dict` `key`) without duplicates (ONE router name per device). Then add each interface found from the RegEx to the correct router name that the interface belongs to.

-- Example of what I how I'd like to store the data: **dict of lists maybe?** --

```
'router1.test.com': ['ae10.100']
'pe9-router.test.com': ['xe-0/0/4', 'xe-0/0/4.0', 'ae10.100']
```

-- **My example text I am working with:** --

```
text = """
router1.test.com:# ae10.100        up    up   CKT/112233//ID Myname
pe9-router.test.com:# xe-0/0/4        up    down CKT2/332211//ID - Myname
pe9-router.test.com:# xe-0/0/4.0        up    down CKT/112233//ID - Myname
pe9-router.test.com:# ae10.100        up    down CKT/112233//ID - Myname
"""
```

-- **CODE SO FAR** --

```
findme_rancid_juniper_regex = re.compile(
    r"(?P<rancid_files>^.*?):#\s*(?P<juniper_ifaces>[gxel][et]-[0-9]*/[0-9]*/[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|ae[0-9]*\.[0-9]*)", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

rancid_filename_match_list = [m.groups() for m in findme_rancid_juniper_regex.finditer(text)]
```

-- **ipython3 output of the above code** ---

```
In [67]: rancid_filename_match_list
Out[67]: 
[('router1.test.com', 'ae10.100'),
 ('switch9.test.com', 'xe-0/0/4'),
 ('switch9.test.com', 'xe-0/0/4.0'),
 ('switch9.test.com', 'ae10.100')]
```

As my ipython3 output shows it isn't working how I'd like it to. I hope someone can lend some help please.

I've tried many different ways of getting my idea into code, but I can never get the router names to not duplicate - unless I use a python `set`, but when I use a `set` I cannot figure out how to add the interface names specifically to the only router that they should belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionary where keys are the hostnames and values are lists with interfaces:

```py
import re

text = """
router1.test.com:# ae10.100        up    up   CKT/112233//ID Myname
pe9-router.test.com:# xe-0/0/4        up    down CKT2/332211//ID - Myname
pe9-router.test.com:# xe-0/0/4.0        up    down CKT/112233//ID - Myname
pe9-router.test.com:# ae10.100        up    down CKT/112233//ID - Myname
"""

out = {}
for k, v in re.findall(r"(\S+):# (\S+)", text):
    out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "router1.test.com": ["ae10.100"],
    "pe9-router.test.com": ["xe-0/0/4", "xe-0/0/4.0", "ae10.100"],
}
```

Comment: That looks perfect! I need to test this to figure out the traversal of the dict of lists. Thank you very much